# Rendering Bernoulli sampling by the binomial distribution

Tags: data-visualization, binomial-distribution, bernoulli-process

I want to characterize the simple algorithm for selecting, say, 20% of a discrete set when the total size of the set is not known:

```
foreach item in the set
   generate a random non-negative integer R
   if (R mod 100) < 20 then
      select item
```

Does that algorithm have a name?  Is it the same as *Algorithm $B\mathcal U$* in [Binomial random variate generation](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/42372.42381)? (The algorithm there has "generate $u \sim \mathcal U(0,1)$" instead of a random integer, and uses $\le$ instead of $\lt$.  Algorithm cited [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100503/simple-scheme-to-sample-from-the-bernoulli-distribution#100513))

The probability of ending up with $k$ items after examining $n$ of them can be calculated using the binomial distribution as:
$$f(n, k) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
where $p=\frac{20}{100} = 0.2\quad$ in this example.  However, plotting the resulting values for widely different $n$ results in non-comparable graphs.  In the picture below, I plotted the values of $f(n,k)$, scaling the interval $[0, n]$ in abscissa to the unit interval $[0, 1]$, and multiplying $f(n, k)$ by $n/10$ in ordinate, so as to compensate for shrinking the abscissa.  (That way, the "integral" of the curve appears to be preserved.)  For high values of $n$ I compute the average of a few $k$'s.  Since the results are rather high, I use a logarithmic scale.

[image: Binomial distribution for p=0.2]

I'd like to show the picture above in a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_sampling).  However, the explanation above smells of [original research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:No_original_research).  Is there an accepted way to scale those functions so as to compare them? Are there references that justify them?

*Note:* cross posted to [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236764/rendering-bernoulli-sampling-by-the-binomial-distribution/), I didn't know of this site.

Comment: "generate a random integer R" doesn't seem well defined. Do you mean random integer between 1 and 100? Or really any integer?

Comment: Also generating random integer uniformly at random is basically the same as generating random float from continuous uniform distribution. The rest of the algorithm is just “throw a coin to decide” and doesn’t have special name.

Comment: This is essentially the binomial distribution, with $p=0.20$ and $n=|\text{set}|.$

Comment: bdeonovic: I'll edit s/integer/natural number/. 
Tim: Yet Kachitvichyanukul and Schmeise call it "Algorithm BU".
Adrian Keister: yes, exactly!

Comment: @Adrian Keister: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer?
[Better to have a short answer than no answer at
all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/)
Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sure, I guess. It'll probably get flagged as a poor quality answer, but here goes.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the binomial distribution, with $p=0.20$ and $n=|\text{set}|,$ the number of elements in the set.

Comment: Does that mean the scaled graphs renders the intrinsic nature correctly?

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with a logarithmic scale, as long as it's clearly called out, which you've done. For some plots, particularly those that cross many orders of magnitude, a logarithmic scale is much more illuminating than a linear one.